# Give User Permission to Run a Command with Sudo Debian

Tags: bash, terminal, command, debian, sudo

I am trying to give a user the permission to run only a command with sudo (**NOT ALL COMMANDS**). For the sake of the question, let's say:

- My username is: **test**
- Command to run: **sudo apt-get install**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `<user> <hostname> = <full path to commands>` to your `/etc/sudoers` file. In your case it would be `test ALL = /usr/bin/apt-get`

Take a look at the `sudoers(5)` man page for more info.